# Specs satisfying the `app_settings (from `.symlinks/plugins/app_settings/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, cocoapods

I run `pod install` for my Flutter app, I'm getting this error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "app_settings":
  In Podfile:
    app_settings (from `.symlinks/plugins/app_settings/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `app_settings (from `.symlinks/plugins/app_settings/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

```
Pre-downloading: `FirebaseFirestore` from `https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git`, tag `10.12.0`
cloud_firestore: Using user specified Firebase SDK version '10.12.0'
cloud_functions: Using user specified Firebase SDK version '10.12.0'
firebase_analytics: Using user specified Firebase SDK version '10.12.0'
firebase_auth: Using user specified Firebase SDK version '10.12.0'
firebase_core: Using user specified Firebase SDK version '10.12.0'
Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5
Ignoring ffi-1.15.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.12.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.12.2
Ignoring nio4r-2.5.7 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 2.5.7
Warning: firebase_app_id_file.json file does not exist. This may cause issues in upload-symbols. If this error is unexpected, try running flutterfire configure again.
firebase_crashlytics: Using user specified Firebase SDK version '10.12.0'
firebase_dynamic_links: Using user specified Firebase SDK version '10.12.0'
firebase_messaging: Using user specified Firebase SDK version '10.12.0'
firebase_remote_config: Using user specified Firebase SDK version '10.12.0'
firebase_storage: Using user specified Firebase SDK version '10.12.0'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "app_settings":
  In Podfile:
    app_settings (from `.symlinks/plugins/app_settings/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `app_settings (from `.symlinks/plugins/app_settings/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Podfile version:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

```
Flutter 3.10.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f468f3366c (3 weeks ago) • 2023-07-12 15:19:05 -0700
Engine • revision cdbeda788a
Tools • Dart 3.0.6 • DevTools 2.23.1
```

Answer (score 7):

if you check the pubspec of app_settings `5.0.0`, it mentions `iOS 15` being the min deployment target.

If you want to use `5.0.0`, you must change your podfile. otherwise, ensure your pubspec file limits the version up to `4.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by running `flutter precache --ios`.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this will help but mine got fix cause I downloaded the arm64 flutter version where as required